# What is the last function in iPhone application lifecycle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Before my application is going to be closed I have to logout user from web service. And I can't find the very last function that is invoked before application die?

```
-(void)LogoutUser
{    
    int userId = [[GlobalData sharedMySingleton] getUserId];

    NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>...", userId
     ];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://....asmx"];     

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];   
    [req addValue:@"http://..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];  
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];   
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (conn) 
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }     

}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response 
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    [webData appendData:data];  
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
{   
    [webData release];    
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{   
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                        length:[webData length] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    


    [theXML release];    

    [connection release];
    [webData release];   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't? Try looking in your app delegate.

Comment: By default iOS apps just goes to the background, ie suspended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two places you'll need to trigger your logout code from, both of which are detailed in the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) documentation.

For pre-iOS 4 devices (and to cover other circumstances) you should use:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

As Apple puts it:

> For applications that do not support
>   background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this
>   method is always called when the user
>   quits the application. For
>   applications that support background
>   execution, this method is generally
>   not called when the user quits the
>   application because the application
>   simply moves to the background in that
>   case. However, this method may be
>   called in situations where the
>   application is running in the
>   background (not suspended) and the
>   system needs to terminate it for some
>   reason.

However, you'll need to use...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

...on iOS 4+ devices, as (once again from the Apple docs):

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is
>   called instead of the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method when
>   the user quits an application that
>   supports background execution

That said, irrespective of all the above, you'll most likely want to logout of the web service when your app is backgrounded and log back in when it's "woken up" as well. See the above mentioned `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method and the `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method documentation for more details.

Comment: I have some problem with this. I put code that logout user from service in applicationDidEnterBackground. But it doesn't complete execution. I tap iPhone button and app goes down. Then I double tap iPhone button and close application. But service call is not over. When I start application again it finishes the web service call :(

Comment: @1110 Have you read about the `applicationWillResignActive:` method?

Comment: Yes I tried to put web service call there too but the same problem again :(

Comment: @1110 If that's the case, then you're possibly out of luck. How are you calling the web service? (Asynchronously or ?)

Comment: @1110 Hmm.. it's a pity you can use a "fire and forget" approach in this instance, as setting up an NSURLConnection and associated delegates is probably the last thing you want to do. That said, this is all getting pretty far away from your original question, which was answered above. I'd be tempted to create a new once specifically about how best to speedily close a web service.

Comment: I opened new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604035/web-service-consuming-from-iphone-approach

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
/*
 Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
 If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
 */
}
```

this may be not a last function but. you can do logout here.

Comment: you can found this method in app delegate. :)

Comment: That's not when the application dies. The application is still running even when this is called. In fact, if you read the comment Apple provides, it says "in case it is terminated later", so calling this means it hasn't terminated **yet**.

Comment: as per his question he can do logout in this method. why downvote?

Comment: Because it's not "the last function in iPhone application lifecycle".

Comment: @BoltClock what he asking is Before my application is going to be closed I have to logout user from web service. And I can't find the very last function

Comment: @BoltClock It's apparently the last function called on iOS 4 devices. (See my updated answer.)

Answer (score 0):

For typical apps under iOS 4.x, applicationWillResignActive and perhaps applicationDidEnterBackground will be called both before your app is terminated (at some unknown time in the future), and at other times as well when the app isn't being terminated.  However it might be a good idea to log out here, as your app may never get any further CPU run time.

If you have pending network activity, such as trying to logout, you might want to use the multitasking call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: to request a bit of additional time in the background to finish the log out process, such as handshaking with any network callbacks required.