# Web service consuming from iPhone approach

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap

How can I improve this code?
This question is related to [What is the last function in iPhone application lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603693/what-is-the-last-function-in-iphone-application-lifecycle)

```
-(void)LogoutUser
{    
    int userId = [[GlobalData sharedMySingleton] getUserId];

    NSString *soapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>...", userId
     ];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://....asmx"];     

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];   
    [req addValue:@"http://..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];  
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];   
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if (conn) 
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }     

}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response 
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    [webData appendData:data];  
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
{   
    [webData release];    
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{   
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                        length:[webData length] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    


    [theXML release];    

    [connection release];
    [webData release];   
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? What would you like to see improved?

Comment: The problem comes from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603693/what-is-the-last-function-in-iphone-application-lifecycle It seams that there is some other way to invoke web service. The problem occur when I try to call service method when I close iPhone application. It gets into '-(void)LogoutUser' but never get into 'connectionDidFinishLoading'. But when I start application again it calls 'connectionDidFinishLoading'. So I am a little lost here :(

Comment: I suggest you sum up the problem you experience and put it into the question itself instead of just linking to the previous question. It helps people to understand your problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your application switches to the background state, it no longer receives any network updates. If you require the network call to return before the application enters the background, maybe a synchronous call will help you there.

If you decide to go this route, I also suggest to look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) because those classes will allow you to set a timeout on the synchronous call while the normal `NSURLConnection` classes won't. Otherwise you risk that your application will be terminated by the iOS if the server does not respond.